# css positioning child divs

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to do this using css (and how)?

```
------------------------------------------
|  ----------   ----------   ----------  |
|  | Child 1 |  | Child 3 |  | Child 5 | |
|  ----------   ----------   ----------  |
|  ----------   ----------   ----------  |
|  | Child 2 |  | Child 4 |  | Child 6 | |
|  ----------   ----------   ----------  |
|  ----------                            |
|  | Child 7 |                           |
|  ----------                            |
|  ----------                            |
|  | Child 8 |                           |
|  ----------                            |
------------------------------------------
```

using the following :

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">Child1</div>
   <div class="child">Child2</div>
   <div class="child">Child3</div>
   <div class="child">Child4</div>
   <div class="child">Child5</div>
   <div class="child">Child6</div>
   <div class="child">Child7</div>
   <div class="child">Child8</div>
</div>

.parent {width:100%}
.parent div {width:100px; margin:2px;}
```

Edit:
Maybe I didn't explain clearly what i want...so

1. There can be more than 8 children.....but always an even number (10,12,14 etc)
2. A div with an even number must be always under his preceding odd div (2 under 1, 4 under 3....8 under 7, 10 under 9)
3. When parent's width is not enough to hold pairs of childer: it expands its height (like starts a new line)

Edit2:
The correct result is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/97ZpN/3/

but in this solution i had to put every pair of divs into a sub-container. Is it posiible to do it with the original html?

Comment: Something like this :P http://jsfiddle.net/XLSt9/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

hope it will help you

```
    .parent {width:100%}
 .parent div {float:left; margin:2px;width:30%}
 .parent div.child:nth-child(7),.parent div.child:nth-child(8){
  float:none;
  clear:both;
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/97ZpN/

**Explanation:**

```
.parent div {float:left; margin:2px;width:30%}
```

This line in the CSS will make all the child elements to float towards the left. So the elements will automatically stack one after other.

```
 .parent div.child:nth-child(7),.parent div.child:nth-child(8){
      float:none;
      clear:both;
    }
```

The clear:both does the trick here. clear:both means there cannot be any elements on the left or right side of the referenced element.

Comment: Good code, but might be worth giving OP a brief explanation of how `float` works. I'm guessing he won't know what it does if he didn't think of it already.
*"Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime"*

Comment: Edit:
Maybe I didn't explain clearly what i want...so
1. There can be more than 8 children.....but always an even number (10,12,14 etc)
2. A div with an even number must be always under his preceding odd div (2 under 1, 4 under 3....8 under 7, 10 under 9)
3. When parent's width is not enough to hold pairs of childer: it expands its height (like starts a new line)

Comment: The target result i've done here: http://jsfiddle.net/97ZpN/3/...but there i had to put div pairs inside a sub container. Is there a way to do it with the original html?